# Dúvida mySQL e Left Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Tenho o SQL abaixo, que retorna dados que irei preencher alguns inputs de um formulário. O problema é que tenho 20 itens(peças) nessa tabela, mas ele pode estar vazio, pois o usuário pode preencher qualquer quantidade. A descrição da peça está na tabela dela (peças) e nas ocorrências tem somente o código (cod_peccin). Como poderia fazer para ele trazer a descrição onde estiver preenchido e onde não tiver não trazer nada? Tentei usar left join, mas não consegui, abaixo a query original:

*OBS: No Oracle usava o (+) ao lado da variável que poderia ser nula e dava certo, no MySQL não achei nada semelhante fora o left join.*

```
SELECT o.*, DATE_FORMAT(O.dt_abertura, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_abertura, DATE_FORMAT(O.dt_fechamento, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_fechamento,
               DATE_FORMAT(O.data_inicio_1, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_inicio_1, DATE_FORMAT(O.data_inicio_2, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_inicio_2,
               DATE_FORMAT(O.data_inicio_3, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_inicio_3, DATE_FORMAT(O.data_inicio_4, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_inicio_4,
               DATE_FORMAT(O.data_inicio_5, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_inicio_5, DATE_FORMAT(O.data_inicio_6, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_inicio_6,
               DATE_FORMAT(O.data_fim_1, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_fim_1, DATE_FORMAT(O.data_fim_2, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_fim_2,
               DATE_FORMAT(O.data_fim_3, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_fim_3, DATE_FORMAT(O.data_fim_4, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_fim_4,
               DATE_FORMAT(O.data_fim_5, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_fim_5, DATE_FORMAT(O.data_fim_6, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_fim_6,
               e.descricao as descrMaquina, s.nome_setor as descrSetor, P1.DESCRICAO as DESC_1, P2.DESCRICAO as DESC_2, P3.DESCRICAO as DESC_3,P4.DESCRICAO as DESC_4,P5.DESCRICAO as DESC_5,P6.DESCRICAO as DESC_6,
               P7.DESCRICAO as DESC_7,P8.DESCRICAO as DESC_8,P9.DESCRICAO as DESC_9,P10.DESCRICAO as DESC_10,P11.DESCRICAO as DESC_11,P12.DESCRICAO as DESC_12,P13.DESCRICAO as DESC_13,P14.DESCRICAO as DESC_14,
               P15.DESCRICAO as DESC_15,P16.DESCRICAO as DESC_16,P17.DESCRICAO as DESC_17,P18.DESCRICAO as DESC_18,P19.DESCRICAO as DESC_19,P20.DESCRICAO as DESC_20
               FROM ocorrencias O, equipamento E, pecas P1,pecas P2,pecas P3,pecas P4,pecas P5,pecas P6,pecas P7,pecas P8,pecas P9,pecas P10,pecas P11,pecas P12,pecas P13,pecas P14,pecas P15,pecas P16,
                    pecas P17,pecas P18,pecas P19,pecas P20, setores S
               WHERE
               E.COD_EQUIPAMENTO = O.MAQUINA and
               S.centro_custo = O.setor and
               O.cod = 1 AND
               P1.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_1 AND
               P2.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_2 AND
               P3.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_3 AND
               P4.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_4 AND
               P5.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_5 AND
               P6.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_6 AND
               P7.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_7 AND
               P8.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_8 AND
               P9.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_9 AND
               P10.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_10 AND
               P11.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_11 AND
               P12.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_12 AND
               P13.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_13 AND
               P14.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_14 AND
               P15.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_15 AND
               P16.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_16 AND
               P17.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_17 AND
               P18.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_18 AND
               P19.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_19 AND
               P20.COD_PECCIN = O.ITEM_20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devias de fazer com INEERS JOINS, ou LEFT JOINS, ou RIGHT JOINS entre as tabelas, ou seja, FROM tabela1 LEFT JOIN tabela2 ... LEFT JOIN tabela3 ...

Espero que esta imagem te consiga ajudar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]